# Optimize javascript number function

Tags: javascript, optimization, methods, numbers

My target is to get floor of number with javascript. For example:

```
// 23 -> 20;
// 234 -> 230;
// 2345 -> 2300;
...
```

I am using next function:

```
var usersCount = 23;
var rounded;
if (usersCount < 100) {
    rounded = Math.floor(usersCount / 10) * 10;
} else if (usersCount < 1000) {
    rounded = Math.floor(usersCount / 100) * 100;
} else if (usersCount < 10000) {
    rounded = Math.floor(usersCount / 1000) * 1000;
} else if (usersCount < 100000) {
    rounded = Math.floor(usersCount / 10000) * 10000;
} else if (usersCount < 1000000) {
    rounded = Math.floor(usersCount / 100000) * 100000;
} else {
    rounded = usersCount;
}
```

I need to improve that function to be dynamic in order to avoid putting else ifs or any kind of switches. How can I do that? I there any better approach to achieve wanted result?

Comment: Your examples don't match up. Don't you want `234` get rounded to `200`, and get `2345` get rounded to `2000`?

Comment: Also, do you actually want to round (e.g. `27` =>`30`) or really floor the numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function like this:

```js
const userCount = 234567;

const roundIt = n => {
 const numberLength = Math.ceil(Math.log10(n + 1));
  const decrease = n > 100 ? 2 : 1;
  return Math.floor(n / Math.pow(10, numberLength - decrease)) * Math.pow(10, numberLength - decrease);
};

// Display user count
document.querySelector(".user-count").innerHTML = userCount;

// Display rounded count
document.querySelector(".user-count-rounded").innerHTML = roundIt(userCount);
```

```html
<h1>
User count: <span class="user-count">0</span>
</h1>
<h1>
Rounded user count: <span class="user-count-rounded">0</span>
</h1>
```

We use the length of the number and round it using the same code you've written.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/anandchowdhary/fj0zk1x8/7/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the length of the string to calculate the multiplier using [Math.pow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow):

```
const usersCount = 23;    
const round = s => {
    let c = Math.pow(10, s.toString().length - 1);
    return Math.floor(s / c) * c;
};
console.log(round(usersCount)); // 20
```

```js
const round = s => {
  let c = Math.pow(10, s.toString().length - 1);
  return Math.floor(s / c) * c;
};
[
  23,
  199,
  888,
  99999,
  100001
].forEach(x => {
  console.log(round(x));
});
```

Comment: Or simply `Math.pow(10, x.toString().length)`. No need to create a number string from an array and then parse it.

Comment: @Bergi Of course, you are totally right, thank you! I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The most compact and optimised way I can think of right now to re-write your code is as follows:

```
let usersCount = 23;
let rounded;
let x = 10 ** (usersCount.toString().length - 1);
rounded = Math.floor(usersCount / x) * x;
```

It should work recursively with no limitations as you requested.

Answer (score 0):

The following function reproduces the behaviour given in your examples:

```
function f(x) {
    var m, u;
    m = Math.floor(Math.log10(x));
    u = Math.pow(10, Math.max(1, m - 1));
    return u * Math.floor(x / u);
}
```

If you would be happy with rounding to 2 significant figures you could use

```
function f(x) {
    return Number.parseFloat(x.toPrecision(2));
}
```